# Deserialize JSON string when there is dynamic type JSON array in that object

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a JSON string like this

```
{
Success :1,PageNumber :1,TotalPages :5,Data:[{projectName:'Pr1',ProjectId:'p3452'},{projectName:'Pr2',ProjectId:'p5485'}....]
}
```

Here is my class structure for that

```
 public class KipReport
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Here the Data part I cant specify a constant type because it may change from report to report... I some other reports data will be like

```
{
reportID:33,pageNumber:1,totalPages:15,Data:[{EmpName:'EMP1',Department:'R&D',EmpId:234},{EmpName:'Emp2',Department:'Software Development',EmpId:366}....]
}
```

So I have different classes for these Data part

```
class project{
public string ProjectId{get;set;}
public string ProjectName{get;set}
}

class Employee{
public string EmpName{get;set;}
publis string EmpId{get;set;}
public string Department{get;set}
}
```

This is how I deserialize using Newtonsoft

```
rpt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KipReport>(responseBody);
```

So once the rpt is deserialized (works fine) I have a switch case in which i am taking the Data part into corresponding object

```
Switch(reportid){
 case 1:
    List<Project> jsonPS = new List<Project>();
    jsonPS =(List<Project>)rpt.Data;
    break;
  case 2:
    List<Employee> jsonPS = new List<Employee>();
    jsonPS =(List<Employee>)rpt.Data;
    break;

}
```

But its not at all working and this is the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[common.ProjectS]'.

So what I did wrong or how can I make it work

Comment: `class KipReport<T>{ public IList<T> Data { get; set; } }`. and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KipReport<fooBar>>(responseBody)` ? something like this to pass the type

Comment: Do you know the type of Data to expect before you deserialize the JSON, or do you only find out what it is after you deserialize it and look at the `reportID`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make the `KipReport` generic.

```
public class KipReport<T>
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    public int RecordsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Data { get; set; } // Also note here, it is a List, not a single object
}
```

When you deserialize, specify the type:
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KipReport<project>>(responseBody);`
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KipReport<Employee>>(responseBody);`

If you want to know the type before deserializing, so that you know which deserialization to perform, maybe perform  a string check by some keyword beforehand.

Comment: You can also `public T Data { get; set; }`, so you will be able to handle what ever result you have: `string`, `List<string>`, `customType`, `List<CustomType>` 
 `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WrapperType<string>>("{\"Data\":\"This is not an array nor a object\"}");`

Comment: Sorry its saying Type or Namespace T could not be found

Comment: `class KipReport<T>` not `class KipReport`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this way:

```
var result = rpt.Data.OfType<Employee>();
var result2 = rpt.Data.OfType<project>();
```

Example:

```
object[] obj = { 1, "2" };
var result = obj.OfType<string>();
// result = "2"
```

Comment: why not use a json deserializing library like newton soft